# I had this question on fluid statics, it's too long to fit in the title

Tags: fluid-statics

Imagine taking a jar and filling it with water(not completely but say half). Then add a weight to the water. By Archemedis principle, the weight of the object should be equal to the weight of the water displaced. If the object displace some water, the pressure just below the block is same at every point at that height right but when the displaced water rises up at every point on the surface except which the block is placed. Then doesn't the pressure at height just below the block be different at where the block is and where the block is not there. This shouldn't happen atleast of what I've been thought which is pressure at equal heights from the surface are always equal

Comment: but that is what the Archimedes principle is about, That whether the weight is the weight of water or of an immersed body, the forces involved are the same, so how could there be a difference blow the bock from before the immersion ?